# IdentityServer4 Session Cookie Management (how to do it properly?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, single-page-application, session-cookies

We are working on an idetityserver4 (A SPA application in angular) that will run on a standalone server and will comunicate with an API(asp.net API) that is on another server, the patern we are trying to implement is BFF (backend for front end) and if we didn't misunderstand the concept badly, our ID4 will act as the gateway to the API, firstly we log to the ID4 with the ClientID and secret so that we get a token and generate the session cookies, afterward we forward everything to the API to complete the local login.
Everything works fine till here, we get the response we want, token gets set to acces the API and cookies generated for that client are automatically returned in Header (we use POSTMAN), but when i try to make a request to the API (request that firstly goes to ID4 to get verified if the client cookie is not expired) apparently ID4 does not verify if the client cookie is or not expired, i can make as many requests as i like....
We really don't understand how to do it properly and we didn't find something that can help us...

Here are the snippets

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            options.RequireAuthenticatedSignIn = true;
        })
    .AddCookie("cookies", options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "cookie-bff";
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = 0;
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.Events.OnSigningOut = async e =>
        {
            // revoke refresh token on sign-out
            await e.HttpContext.RevokeUserRefreshTokenAsync();
        };
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:4001/";
        options.ClientId = "angular-client";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";

        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        /*
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("api");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        */
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            RoleClaimType = "role"
        };
    });

        services.AddAccessTokenManagement(options =>
        {
            // client config is inferred from OpenID Connect settings
            // if you want to specify scopes explicitly, do it here, otherwise the scope parameter will not be sent
            options.Client.Scope = "write";
        })
        .ConfigureBackchannelHttpClient();

        services.AddUserAccessTokenClient("user_client", client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/api/");
        });

        services.AddClientAccessTokenClient("client", configureClient: client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/api/");
        });
```

Where we configure the Context for operation and configuration

```
 services.AddIdentityServer(options => {
            options.Authentication.CheckSessionCookieName = "cookie-bff";
            options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            options.Authentication.CookieSameSiteMode = SameSiteMode.Strict;
            options.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = true;
            options.LowerCaseIssuerUri = false;
            options.EmitScopesAsSpaceDelimitedStringInJwt = false;
            })
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("LocalDevelopment"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
                })
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("LocalDevelopment"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
                });
```

This is our LoginController(its work in progres, we are beginers)

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("/identityserver/login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([Required, FromBody] LoginPostDTO Json)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.RequestTokenAsync(new TokenRequest
        {
            Address = "https://localhost:4001/connect/token",
            GrantType = "client_credentials",

            ClientId = "angular-client",
            ClientSecret = "secret",

            Parameters =
{
    { "scope", "read"},
    {"openid","profile"}
}
        });
       
        var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name,"Company"),
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, "Company")
            };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "cookies");

        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            // Refreshing the authentication session should be allowed.

            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1),
            // The time at which the authentication ticket expires. A 
            // value set here overrides the ExpireTimeSpan option of 
            // CookieAuthenticationOptions set with AddCookie.

            IsPersistent = false,
            // Whether the authentication session is persisted across 
            // multiple requests. When used with cookies, controls
            // whether the cookie's lifetime is absolute (matching the
            // lifetime of the authentication ticket) or session-based.

            IssuedUtc = DateTime.Now,
            // The time at which the authentication ticket was issued.

            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:4001/signin-oidc"
            // The full path or absolute URI to be used as an http 
            // redirect response value.
        };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync("cookies", new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);

        var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Json), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var api = new HttpClient();
        api.SetBearerToken(response.AccessToken);

        var apiResponse = await api.PostAsync("https://localhost:5001/api/login", stringContent);

        return Ok(apiResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync(typeof(JObject)).Result);
    }
}
```

And here is the Controller where we comunicate with the API after we login

```
public class Controller : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/identityserver/request")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([Required, FromBody]DTO Json)
    {   
        var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Json), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var api = new HttpClient();
        api.SetBearerToken(await HttpContext.GetClientAccessTokenAsync());

        var apiResponse = await api.PostAsync("https://localhost:5001/api/request/medical-request", stringContent);

        return Ok(apiResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync(typeof(JObject)).Result);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

P.S This is my first post on stack :)

Comment: You should get an expires_in value back from IDS4 when you call /connect/token. You'll have to manually handle that in your API. The best approach will be to use an IProfileService inside your IDS4 app to set the claims for the token. That way you can check them inside your API within your oidc middleware (startup.cs). oidc has a callback events option which will intercept all messages coming in (OnMessageReceived). Inside that, check if your token has expired. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents?view=aspnetcore-5.0